# Compiling C files on Ubuntu and using them on Android

Tags: android, c, ubuntu

so today I've tried to use my C code in Android. I've made it work on intellij with regular generated dll files. From what I've understood, Android uses .so files instead of .dll files. So I've compiled with ubuntu and gcc, using the following commandline : 
`gcc -m32 -fPIC -o libilcore.so -shared -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/include/linux java.c -lc` this went fine, no errors whatsoever and I got the .so file. I've put it in the jniLibs directory, and inside I made a armeabi directory, However when I try to load the library, it says 
`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/org.packagename.test-1/lib/arm/libilcore.so" has unexpected e_machine: 3`
I have no clue on what this means, I've looked it up on google, its either the wrong way to compile on ubuntu or I've done something else wrong, can anyone please help? 
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you compile the C code on and x86 machine and then try to run it on an ARM machine?

Comment: It means that binary, you've built, is incompatible with your android CPU architecture. To run C/C++ code on Android it must be compiled by proper toolchain.  [Android NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/index.html) is the official toolset for your purpose.

Comment: I'm not so sure, my machine is an x64 bits Intel machine, I compiled with -m32 because the library was in 64 bits apparantly. I'm not sure if this was the right way. My phone is an ARM type

Comment: Machine code is (at least) architecture-specific.  You need to compile for the correct target architecture, and if that architecture is different from the one on which the compilation is performed then that requires engaging a special tool called a "cross compiler" that can generate code for a different architecture than the one on which it is running.

Comment: Oh so I have to compile it with Android NDK and it'll give me the .so files so I can remove the .c and .h files later?

Comment: i suggest you to install the latest version of Android Studio and `Import an Android code sample` that uses NDK

Comment: it may be good for you to take a time to study how a CPU works, about different CPU architectures, compilers, assemblers, linkers, static libraries, dynamic libraries and executables